# Nginx not starting after installed [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

Right after installing Nginx on Ubuntu, it's not starting. I've no idea what's happening. I tried created nginx.conf by myself but no changed happened

```
    ● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2021-01-08 15:12:18 UTC; 1min 49s ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)

Jan 08 15:12:18 root systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Jan 08 15:12:18 root nginx[3367]: nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or d
Jan 08 15:12:18 root nginx[3367]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Jan 08 15:12:18 root systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 08 15:12:18 root systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 08 15:12:18 root systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

Comment: Can you show your /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file?

Comment: actually, there is no nginx.conf file inside /etc/nginx/

Comment: https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/conf/nginx.conf

Comment: I have no idea but it works after i've copied nginx.conf and mime.types inside /etc/nginx from your link. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no idea but it works after I've copied nginx.conf and mime.types inside /etc/nginx from [this link](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/conf/nginx.conf). Thank you @Daniel Mesa

Comment: Actually, this link contains the default format of the Nginx config file, and if someone runs any command related to Nginx by mistake, that command effect is indirectly reflected in it. So this option is better to reset